# If $U$ is open, is it true that $U = \operatorname{Int}(\overline{U})$?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Can someone please verify this proof? I am aware that there must be a similar question elsewhere, but I need help with my proof in particular.

> If $U$ is open, is it true that $U = \operatorname{Int}(\overline{U})$?

No. Consider the set $\mathbb{R}$ under the finite complement topology. Set $U = \mathbb{R} - \{1, 2, 3\}$. Then,  $\overline{U} = \mathbb{R}$, and $\operatorname{Int}(\overline{U}) = \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: All you have shown is that the set $\overline U = \mathbb{R}$ does not contradict the statement: it is open, and it is equal to its interior. You have shown nothing about the set $U$ itself.

Comment: @LeeMosher Sorry, copied the question wrong. It's now fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Just consider $U = (0, 1) \cup (1, 2)$, which is open in $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology. Then $U \neq \mathrm{Int}(\overline{U})$ because $ 1 \notin U$ while $1 \in \mathrm{Int}(\overline{U})$.

Answer (score 0):

Try the rationals.  Then this conjecture fails spectacularly.
If open is what you want, enumerate the rationals with $x_n$ and put
$$G = \bigcup_n(x_n-\epsilon/2^n, x_n + \epsilon/2^n).$$
This set is tiny, its closure is the line.